# ¿Como logro instertar un imagen con mpdf?

Tags: php, php7, mpdf

```
<?php 

    require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
    //require_once('vendor/autoload.php');
    $mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();

    //image(Str filename, int x, int y, int width, int height, str ext, str href_link, bool paint, bool constrain, bool watermark, bool, shownoimg, bool allowVector )

    //$mpdf->Image('img/preta.jpg', 0, 0, 'jpg');

    $mpdf->Image('files/images/frontcover.jpg', 0, 0, 210, 297, 'jpg', '', true, false);
    //$mpdf->WriteHTML();
    $mpdf->Output();
 ?>
```

Se genera el pdf pero no se ve la imagen. La idea es agregar una imagen al lado izquierdo de la hoja como un membretado.

Comment: La línea de uso de la imagen `$mpdf->Image('files/images/frontcover.jpg', 0, 0, 210, 297, 'jpg', '', true, false);` es correcta según la doc. Comprueba que la imagen es .jpg y seguidamente la ruta a tu fichero. Con  la ruta indicada prueba a ubicar la imagen y usar 'files' como carpeta en la que sirves los recursos públicos (imágenes, css, etc) y con files dentro de 'public/' (sin modificar la ruta de `Image()`).

Comment: Lo hice cree la carpeta files y ultilice los mismoos nombres. Lo de 'public/' no le entendí.

Comment: en un proyecto web es habitual situar directorios css, js, images, etc dentro de un directorio public en la raíz del proyecto, ya que estos recursos están disponibles *publicamente* a través de la web.

Comment: Como retroalimentación: Utilice la clase SetWatermarkImage para agregar imagenes. Porque al parecer no soy el unico con este problema.

Answer (score 0):

Yo imprimi la informacion que queria en un string concatenado.

```
<?php 
require_once("vendor/autoload.php"); 

/* Configuracion */
$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf([
    'mode' => 'utf-8',
    'format' => 'Letter'
]);

/* Cuerpo del documento */
$data = '';
$data .= '
<style>
    h1 {
        background-color: red;
    }
</style>';
$data .= '<h1>Hello world</h1>';
$data .= '<p>Otro parrafo</p>';
$data .= '<img width = "100" src = "../img/Portada.jpg"/>';

/* Impresion y salida del documento */
$mpdf->WriteHTML($data);
$mpdf->Output();
```

Para que funcione con las imagenes tienes que imprimir el string con comillas simples y lo que son los atributos son con comillas dobles.

Answer (score -1):

Despues de:

```
$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();
```

Puedes poner algo asi:

````
$mpdf->SetHTMLHeader('<img src="assets/images/fuerza_m.png" style="float: right; margin: 0px 0px 15px 15px;" width="160" height="100"/>');```
````

Comment: Describe brevemente _qué hace tu código_: lee [answer].